# Python: Using Regex to remove text with "{ }"

Tags: python, regex

Usually when I want to remove text between two strings using regex in python, I do:

```
s = re.sub('z1.*?AA', '', s, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

Where `s` is my text and I use the above code to remove everything between `z1` and `AA` (including z1 and AA). But now I am struggling to do the same for the following:

I have the following string (from a latex .txt file):

```
\begin{tabular}{lccccc}
\toprule
            &            &            &            &            &             \\
            &    (0)     &    (1)     &    (2)     &    (3)     &    (4)      \\
\hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{llllll}
```

My objective is to replace everything from `\toprule` to the last `}` on the last line.
I tried several regex combinations such as `.*?\{}` and others and no success... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you try using a parser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
s = re.sub(r'\\toprule.*}', '', s, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cR8zH8/1)

`re.DOTALL` makes DOT match any character including newlines and greedy `.*` makes sure to match last `}` in the input.

Comment: Oh sweet! Thank you. Works pefect. Learned something before going to bed.